# crash logs not generated when app crashes on EXC_BAD_ACCESS in main

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

So here's what I am seeing now in my screen:

[image]

Now before I give more detailed explanation, let me just emphasize that this error happened only on iOS 6 on the device. The app works fine otherwise. This is an iPad app.

I have been trying to figure out this crash since this morning, but it's leading me nowhere as there isn't any crash logs generated for this error. I have "Strip debug symbols during copy" set to NO. Not sure where else I should check so that this error gets into my crash log, so I can get more details.

I have turned on NSZombieEnabled to YES, hoping that it would give me some more details on this EXC_BAD_ACCESS, but it still gives me the same result. Can anyone help me on what I can do next to at least get more crash information out of this bizzare crash? Where should I check so that my crash logs is generated.

Comment: If it only happens on iOS 6 then the only answer will most likely be iOS 6 specific (which is still under NDA until tomorrow)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get crash log by using below code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        @try 
        {
            return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([mSellerAppDelegate class]));
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception)
        {

            NSLog(@"%@",[exception callStackSymbols]);
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nice try, but apparently after doing that it goes into the try and then crashes and didn't go to the catch block

Comment: else just set breakpoints on these lines you doubt that can raise exception or crash.